# Response time of Webapplication on glassfish 2.1 suddenly very poor after 2 years without any problems

Tags: gwt, glassfish, smartgwt, sap-ase

We have a web application running for 2 years without any problems.
Suddenly a week ago the response times were becoming very bad. 
About 10-50 times slower than normal.

At a time there are maybe 10-20 users using the system. 
90% of the user requests results in a database request.
The systems responds normal early morning and in the evening when not 
many users are online.

1. How can we detect the problem. Step-by-step documentation to resolve the problem?
2. Are there specialised companies or specialist who could help us solving the problem?

### Environment

Windows Server 2003
Quadcore Intel Xeon X3220, 2.4GHZ, 2 GB Ram
Sybase Anywhere 9 Database - Driver: jconn3.jar
Glassfish 2.1
Internet band width of server: 100MB/s

### Applications

Webapplication with SmartGWT-Frontend  (SmartGwt 2.4)
WebService accessed by external company

No EJBs, only WebContainer

First of all, it doesnt seem that the hardware is at the limit.
Java.exe is sometimes at 25% of CPU usage when heavy request are done, using 374 MB Ram
sybase-db server: 220MB ram
available memory: always around 1GB

### Snapshot of requests

I made a snapshot of all request during 8 Minutes

210 seconds client requests (gwtservice) 45%
Total 967 requests, 212 milliseconds per request

100 seconds webservice (BankOrderService) 20%
Total 86 requests, 1170 milliseconds per request

160 seconds loading frontend elements into browser (.js, .png, jpg, .css etc.)  35%
Total 623 requests, 250 milliseconds per request

### Example of most time consuming requests (in milliseconds):

15427.302   25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user1   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.228    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/091FF14E7C1D1187C770833D67B13321.cache.html
13558.571   25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user1   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.228    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
12631.877   25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user1   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.228    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js
11238.439   25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user1   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.228    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js
10535.141   25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user1   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.228    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js
10003.115   25.07.2012 11:55    Erfolg  anonymous   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.25     URI:/BankWebService/BankOrderService
9999.412    25.07.2012 11:49    Erfolg  anonymous   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.25     URI:/BankWebService/BankOrderService
9999.229    25.07.2012 11:55    Erfolg  anonymous   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.25     URI:/BankWebService/BankOrderService
9992.415    25.07.2012 11:49    Erfolg  anonymous   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.25     URI:/BankWebService/BankOrderService
9990.473    25.07.2012 11:55    Erfolg  anonymous   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.25     URI:/BankWebService/BankOrderService
9132.848    25.07.2012 11:55    Erfolg  user1   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.228    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/gwtservice
5933.174    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user2   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js
5864.426    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user2   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
5571.739    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user2   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js
5473.637    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user2   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js
5158.104    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user3   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.237    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/gwtservice
4488.047    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user2   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162    URI:/BankApp/images/chf.jpg
4442.574    25.07.2012 11:56    Erfolg  user2   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
4072.268    25.07.2012 11:54    Erfolg  anonymous   REMOTE_WEB    xx.yy.zz.25   URI:/BankWebService/BankOrderService
3939.546    25.07.2012 11:56    Erfolg  user2   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162      URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js
3876.443    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user1   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.228      URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js
3727.795    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user4   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162      URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/gwtservice
3630.225    25.07.2012 11:48    Erfolg  user4   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.162      URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/091FF14E7C1D1187C770833D67B13321.cache.html
3552.007    25.07.2012 11:50    Erfolg  user5   REMOTE_WEB  xx.yy.zz.228    URI:/BankApp/org.Bank.Main/gwtservice

### Sessions

18 active Sessions
After a client login (provided by glassfish, https), Once the user is authenticated by glassfish, there there is a second login in the application itself where the user has to define into which branch he wants to login. After the second login, 3 attributes (username, branch, ip-address) are stored in the session.

There are always about 40%-50% of sessions without these 3 attributes, I interpret it like that, that the first login was made but the second not.

examples:
session id:e6df980ab67cf0456d78761eefa1
8 sessions without the 3 attributes

session id:d72d16bdabb5500e73f721475440:{username=user1, branch=000x, ipadr=xx.xx.xx.xx}
10 sessions with the 3 attributs

I thought maybe these 8 sessions are from a hacker? I ran wireshark to find out if
there are some suspicious ip-Addresses, however I havent found a lot.  One day there was
an ip from Sweden and we have nothing in Sweden. However this wasnt a lot of traffic, just a few lines in the wireshark capture log during a few seconds.

### at 7/17/2012 The msn account of one of the users has been hacked.

Around that date the problems started as well. maybe with a delay of 1-2 days.
Coincidence?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Has anything changed in the Environment? Real-time scanner (virus, malware, etc.) scanning every file served? Windows patches? Sybase patches? Are you being DDoS'ed? Also, you might want to ask over on [su] or [webmasters.se].

Comment: Thanks a lot. As far as I know nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do in order:

Restart everything including the OS.  There was the leap second problem a few weeks ago.  I had to restart our glassfish servers because of high CPU usage.  The 25% is probably maxing out a CPU core.  Mine were linux based, and I don't know if it also happened on Windows.

Can you update your glassfish server?  It's quite old and there's a number of known denial of service exploits.  You didn't mention your Java version, but it could probably use an update too.

Turn on access logging on the glassfish server so you can see if you're getting pounded with some scripted requests.   You can do that on the admin console.

Finally look at the database.  Sometimes as tables change the query optimizer starts making poor choices.  I'm not familiar with sybase to be more specific.  In Oracle you need to make sure you're collecting optimizer statistics as tables grow.